# Random text in Corona

Tags: coronasdk

Totally new with Corona and asking for some support.

Would like to create a simple first software with Corona. My idea is to have a button and when you press the button you see different words on the screen. The idea is that they roll randomly and then stops on one word. For example 8 different words and one is chosen and a few seconds and shown on the screen.

For an expert I guess this is imple but for a rookie it´s not that easy.

Answer (score 1):

Use a array of words to store the words

```
local words = {foo, bar, hi, no, yes, mom, dad}
```

Then use math.random to select a word.

```
local wordIwant = math.random(#words) -- # operador gets the length of a list
```

So if math.random returns 3 for example, wordIwant will be "hi"

:)

Now how you do your special effect and other pretty stuff, is up to you, but I recommend using the enterFrame listener for that.

Comment: Many, many thanks for your reply. Still struggling how to get the whole thing behind a button. Any hints here? Idea is that when you press the button the "lottery" starts.